# Difference in rotation matrix

Tags: matrices, transformation, rotations

I have two objects A and B, with a start transformation matrices MA1 and MB1 (they include translation, rotation and scale). End matrix of the first object is MA2. How do I apply the same rotation as a rotation of object A from MA1 to MA2 ( difference)  to object B and get MB2?

Answer (score 0):

First you extract rotation matrix from transformation matrix. You take top-left 3×3 submatrix $T$ and use [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition) to find rotation matrix $U$. If you know that scale is the same on all axes, then you can just divide $T$ by cubic root of determinant: $U=T/\sqrt[3]{\det T}$.

Finally, $U_{1\to2} = U_{A2} U_{A1}^{-1}$

Comment: I have the problem in the final step. I use `B1 *(U1→2)^-1` for object `B` and this looks like it applies the rotation `U1→2` to object `B` around the object's `B` coordinate system. It works as needed if MA1 is identity.